# How to skip cell value if row header contains certain text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a workbook for tracking my inventory in real time.

I want to have my inventory crew count and add the data in line along with the receiving and departing shipments of 12oz bottles. For instance, when we Start the week with 343,520 bottles. This number is totaled out and placed in J5. The next day we check the count and enter in 343,520 and is placed in J6. The totals of the rows pallet and layer count are sumed for each row (or  action) and placed in the L column.

To get the current total on hand, A2 sums L5:L47. However, I do not want the total to reflect as 687,040. Instead I want the equation to reference Column A and see that A6 says 'Inventory' or 'Inventory Count' and know to skil J6 when A2 (Total Bottles on hand) is summing L5:L47.

[image]
[larger view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbei6.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @birdman3131, when I had tried putting the image inline like that, it said I needed more reputation before doing that. :)

Comment: Not sure if i understand your need exactly, but a combination of SUMIF should enable you to do the trick. SUM cell in column L IF cell in column A does not say "Inventory..." and (or plus) SUM cell in column J IF it does.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the SUMIF function. I screwed around with it and got this to work just as I needed it!

Thanks, and I hope this helps someone else too.

=SUMIF(Table1014152427[Action],"<>Inventory Count",Table1014152427[Unit Total])

Comment: You're welcome, looked like all you needed was a hint. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewMcAtee: "bare with me"?  I'll read your question, but I'm not taking MY clothes off.  :-)

Comment: Shucks, was hoping you wouldn't say that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) for this.  You'll want something like:

```
=SUMIF(A5:A47, "<>Inventory*", L5:L47)
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheUser1024 mentioned the SUMIF function and I was able to get this to work. Hope this helps someone with a similar question!

=SUMIF(Table1014152427[Action],"<>Inventory Count",Table1014152427[Unit Total])